# Cloud function is executed many times even though it's called once on client

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

My cloud function is executed many times even though it is called only once on client side.

The log when calling the function is always like this.

> aFunction Function execution started
>   aFunction Function execution took 388 ms, finished with status code: 204
>   aFunction Function execution started
>   aFunction Function execution took 1106 ms, finished with status code: 200
>   Unhandled rejection
>   Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline exceeded
>
> at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:30:26)
>       at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:33)
>       at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
>       at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:75:22)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)

Here is the code on client side.

```
  callCloudFunction() {
    console.log('Function is called.')
    var functions = firebase.functions()
    var aFunction = functions.httpsCallable('aFunction')
    aFunction({
       ...
    })
  },
```

The function is like this. What I want to do is to add cloud task by cloud function, and then the task will trigger other cloud function.

```
exports.aFunction = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const client = new tasks.CloudTasksClient()

  const projectId = functions.config()....
  const queue = 'name'
  const location = functions.config()....

  const parent = client.queuePath(projectId, location, queue)

  const url = 'https:// ... '.cloudfunctions.net/doSomething'

  const task = {
    httpRequest: {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      url: url,
    },
    scheduleTime: {
      seconds: ...
    }, 
  }

  const request = {
    parent: parent,
    task: task,
  }

  client.createTask(request)
})
```

I know there are already similar question here but I couldn't find the solution and the same situation so I post this.
How can I fix this? At least on client side, I make sure it is called only once.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the function.  The log is showing that you're probably making a mistake somewhere that are causing error messages.  Note that there is a difference in HTTP status code between the first and second invocations you show in the log.

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to read the documentation for Firebase [callable type functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).  Callable functions must return a promise with the data to send to the client.  Right now, your function is returning nothing immediately.  Given that, the task might not even be scheduled for execution.

Please read over the documentation for callable functions, and take time to learn how promises work. Any API call that you make to something that returns a promise (including the Cloud Tasks API) should be involved in the final response to the caller.